# How to pass dynamic data from view to route to component?

Tags: angularjs, redux, angular2-routing, angular2-forms, angular2-services

Is it possible to pass dynamic data in body as in angular 1.x support as
from dashboard view :

```
<button ui-sref="getConfig({pageid:111,email:'me@gmail.com'})">
    Get Config Page
</button>

.state('/sign-in', {
    url: '/configpage',
    params: {
        pageid: null,
        email: null,
    },
    controller() {
        // get page2 and its data here & pass it to next view 
    },
});
```

Here my page id is non-confidential but my email is confidential which I don't want to show any how.

How can I achieve same situation in Angular2 since Angular2 is not using controller concept and state?